# Условие WHERE в mysql запросе - выбрать одно из двух

Tags: mysql

Имеются две таблицы вида:

**table1**

```
num !  quantity
900 !   1
905 !   2
906 !   1
907 !   1
908 !   1
```

и

**table2**

```
num !  option
900 !  3
900 !  10
905 !  3
906 !  10
907 !  3
908 !  5
```

Мне нужно просуммировать значения quantity из первой таблицы, когда выполняется table1.id = table2.id и option = 3 ЛИБО 10. Как видно, во второй таблице есть два id=900, одному соответствует option 3, другому - option 10. Если я выполню запрос вида

```
SELECT SUM(table1.quantity) as sumquantity 
from table1, table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id 
  AND (table2.option = '10' OR table2.option = '3')
```

то в результате суммарное кол-во будет равняться 1+1+2+1+1=6, а должно быть 1+2+1+1, то есть 5. Как мне скорректировать sql-запрос, чтобы срабатывало нужное мне ЛИБО в условии WHERE?

Comment: join (запятая) обязательны ? Если нет, я бы написал, `select sum() from tab1 where num in(select num from tab2 where option=10 or option=3)` что бы записи не множились. А с join придется сначала брать max() с группировкой по num, оборачивать еще одним запросом и получать сумму

Comment: или join не с tab2 а с подзапросом, который уникальные num вернет

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(quantity)
FROM table1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
               FROM table2
               WHERE table2.option IN (3, 10)
                 AND table1.num = table2.num )
```